# Finding a string on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to sniff out an IP Address from a HTML code. I currently have a google script api link that gives me this, and I have a ":" and "END" on both ends of the IP Address, and I wanted to use

```
editTexttest.setText(html.substringAfter("L1 IP :", "Not Found"))
editTexttest.setText(html.substringbefore("END", "Not Found"))
```

But the string I get gives me a "Not Found" Is there any other way that I can solve this problem? The String currently is "L1 IP :192.168.0.5END". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
val string = "L1 IP :192.168.0.5END"

val index = string.indexOf("L1 IP :")
if (index == -1) throw IllegalStateException("start not found")
val start = index + 7 // 7 is the len of "L1 IP :" string

val end = string.indexOf("END")
if (end == -1) throw IllegalStateException("end not found")

val result = string.substring(start, end)
println(result)
```

You can try it here: https://pl.kotl.in/CQPUdo8Ne

Comment: I see that we can use .replace after .replace? Also, I understand what you are saying, but I have an entire page of html code to sift the information through, hence the need for a different approach I believe

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val string = "L1 IP :192.168.0.5END L1 IP :192.168.0.6END"

    var indexOfColon = -1
    var indexOfEnd = -1
    while (true) {
        indexOfColon = string.indexOf(":", indexOfColon + 1)
        indexOfEnd = string.indexOf("END", indexOfEnd + 1)
        if(indexOfColon == -1 || indexOfEnd == -1) {
            break
        }
        println(string.substring(indexOfColon + 1, indexOfEnd))

    }
}
```

This code will print multiple IP addresses if present in your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always "L1 IP:" you can do something like this:

```
html.removeSurrounding("L1 IP :", "END")
```

But your code with substringAfter / substringBefore should also work. Are you sure the html is "L1 IP :192.168.0.5END"?

Comment: I believe it is the method in which I got my html code in the first place that was off. Thanks!